# ZeroMQ pub/sub with multiple subscribers on same ip/port

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, zeromq

I'm running multiple Python processes that are using PUB/SUB to wait for a start signal from another machine.  All of these processes are binding to the same port:

```
context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (messenger_ip, pub_port))
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, my_id)

while True:
   subscriber.recv()
   break

# do more stuff here
```

From my logs, I can see that some of the processes receive the message from the publisher, and carry on doing "more stuff".  However, some of the processes just sit there forever.  Is it a problem that I have multiple subscribers on the same IP and port?

I've also tried having the publisher send the message repeatedly (every 5 seconds) for another minute, but those processes just sit there.

Any insight would be appreciated much!  Thanks!